# Avoid dot backslash Windows 10 Powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell

This is a very annoying thing, to run any `.exe` that is inside the current directory in Powershell, I am required to use a `.\` ahead.

For example, if I have the program `fastboot.exe` inside the current folder I can not simply type `fastboot`, as it does inside `cmd`. I'm forced to type:

```
.\fastboot
```

If I just type `fastboot` (without `.\` I get some error like:

> The term 'fastboot' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.
>
> + fastboot
>   + ~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (fastboot:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

How to avoid this?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? I just checked mine and that's not the case. I'm running PS version 5.1. I typed "cd C:\users\xxx\desktop" and then typed "start xxx.xxx" and it opened without a leading ".\" - Could you provide a snippet of your code? The .\ might be needed for another reason.

Comment: *to run any command*...are you sure this is required for *all/any* commands? Not just PowerShell scripts?

Comment: I corrected the post, it would not be "command", but ".exe".

Comment: can you provide the response when you try to use the command like you expect?

Comment: I put the error in the post

Comment: Have you put the .exe in the folder windows\system32\ ?
I test it in my lab,it works well with or without .\

Comment: This is a security feature. In this case, Powershell does the unix/linux thing and does not run commends from the current directory. More here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-to-execute-a-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't like typing `.\command.ps1`, You can just type `command` **and hit tab**. If there is a command.ps1 file in the current directory it will be auto-completed.

I think this is ergonomic enough to keep the security benefit of the default behavior.

Answer (score 11):

Powershell does not load commands from the current location by default.

> Suggestion [3,General]: The command xxx.exe was not found, but
>   does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load
>   commands from the current location by default. If you trust this
>   command, instead type ".\xxx.exe". See "get-help
>   about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

So you are left with two options

- Lower the security barrier by adding the current directory to you path

  ```
   $env:path ="$($env:path);."
  ```
- Get into the habbit of always prefixing the command with `.\`

Comment: I've never heard that `cmd.exe`'s behavior was insecure. If that's a true security vulnerability in `cmd.exe` I'm pretty sure Microsoft would have to updated it...

Comment: @CarlWalsh - This is specific to Powershell and the reasoning is the same is in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4432/63662) question.

Comment: Yes, but if PowerShell thinks it is a security problem to trust the current directory as the PATH, I'm wondering why it's not a security problem for cmd to have that behavior. (Maybe part of this is because PS lets you change directories to network locations or even drives with custom providers? But in cmd you can cd into a network share mapped to a drive, and run untrusted programs there.) Put another way, if you add `.` to the PATH then PS is just as secure as cmd?

Comment: @CarlWalsh - I don't know why `cmd` behaves differently in that regard but I would assume it is left in for backwards compatibility. Afaik, this *is* a security problem in `cmd`. If I can get a domain admin to open a command prompt on my computer, navigate to a folder under my control where I've put a malicious `dir` executable: I can have it do whatever I want. You should post your question as a new question.